# How to read space delimited data, two row types, no fixed width and plenty of missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There's lots of good information out there on how to read space-delimited data with missing values *if the data is fixed-width*.

- http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations-2017/pandas/opening-fixed-width-files/
- [Reading space delimited file in Python/Pandas with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997634/reading-space-delimited-file-in-python-pandas-with-missing-values)
- [ASCII table with consecutive white-spaces as separators and missing data python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472392/ascii-table-with-consecutive-white-spaces-as-separators-and-missing-data-python)

I'm currently trying to read Japan's Meteorological Agency typhoon history data which is supposed to have [this format](https://www.jma.go.jp/jma/jma-eng/jma-center/rsmc-hp-pub-eg/Besttracks/e_format_bst.html), but doesn't actually:

```
# Header rows:
    5    10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   55   60   65   70   75   80
::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|
AAAAA BBBB  CCC DDDD EEEE F G HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH              IIIIIIII

# Data rows:
    5    10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   55   60   65   70   75   80
::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|::::+::::|
AAAAAAAA BBB C DDD EEEE FFFF     GGG     HIIII JJJJ KLLLL MMMM         P
```

It is very similar to NOAA's hurricane best track data, except that it comma delimited, and missing values were given -999 or NaN, which simplified reading the data. Additionally, Japan's data doesn't actually follow the advertised format. For example, column `FFFF` in the data rows don't always have width 4. Sometimes it has width 3.

I must say that I'm at a complete loss as how to process this data into a dataframe. I've investigated the `pd.read_fwf` method, and it initially looked promising until I discovered the malformed columns and the two different row types.

#### My question:

**How can I approach cleaning this data and getting it into a dataframe?** I'd just find a different dataset, but honestly I can't find any comprehensive typhoon data anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went a little deep for you here, because I'm assuming you're doing this in the name of science and if I can help someone trying to understand climate change then its a good cause.

After looking the data over I've noticed the issue is relating to the data being stored in a de-normalized structure. There are 2 ways you can approach this issue off the top of my head. Re-Writing the file to another file to load into pandas or dask is what I'll show, since thats probably the *easiest* way to think about it (but certainly not the most *efficient* for those that will inevitably roast me in the comments)

Think of this like its **Two Separate Tables**, with a 1-to-Many relationship. 1 table for Typhoons and another for the data belonging to a given typhoon.

A decent, but not really efficient way would be to rewrite it to a better **nested structure**, like JSON. Then load the data in using that. Note the 2 distinct types of columns.

**Step 1: map the data out**

There are really 2 tables in one table here. Each typhoon is going to show up as a row that appears like this:
`66666 9119  150 0045 9119 0 6             MIRREILE              19920701`

While the records for that typhoon are going to follow that row (think of this as a separate row:
`20080100 002 3 178 1107  994     035     00000 0000 30600 0200`

Load the File in, reading it as raw lines. By using the [.readlines() method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/file_readlines.htm), we can read each individual line in as an item in a list.

```py
# load the file as raw input
with open('./test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Now that we have that read in, we're going to need to perform some logic to separate some lines from others. It appears the every time there is a Typhoon record, the line is preceded with a '66666', so lets key off that. So, given we look at each individual line in a horribly inefficient loop, we can write some if/else logic to have a look:

```py
if row[:5] == '66666':
   # do stuff
else:
   # do other stuff
```

Thats going to be a pretty solid way to separate that logic for now, which will be useful to guide splitting that up. Now, we need to write a loop that will check that for each row:

```py
# initialize list of dicts
collection = []

def write_typhoon(row: str, collection: Dict) -> Dict:
    if row[:5] == '66666':
       # do stuff
    else:
       # do other stuff

# read through lines list from the .readlines(), looping sequentially
for line in lines:
    write_typhoon(line, collection)
```

Lastly, we're going to need to write some logic to now extract that data out in some manner within the if/then loop inside the write_typhoon() function. I didn't care to do a whole lot of thinking here, and opted for the simplest I could make it: defining the fwf metadata myself. because "yolo":

```py
def write_typhoon(row: str, collection: Dict) -> Dict:
    if row[:5] == '66666':
        typhoon = {
            "AA":row[:5],
            "BB":row[6:11],
            "CC":row[12:15],
            "DD":row[16:20],
            "EE":row[21:25],
            "FF":row[26:27],
            "GG":row[28:29],
            "HH":row[30:50],
            "II":row[51:],
            "data":[]
        }
        # clean that whitespace
        for key, value in typhoon.items():
            if key != 'data':
                typhoon[key] = value.strip()
        collection.append(typhoon)
    else:
        sub_data = {
            "A":row[:9],
            "B":row[9:12],
            "C":row[13:14],
            "D":row[15:18],
            "E":row[19:23],
            "F":row[24:32],
            "G":row[33:40],
            "H":row[41:42],
            "I":row[42:46],
            "J":row[47:51],
            "K":row[52:53],
            "L":row[54:57],
            "M":row[58:70],
            "P":row[71:]
        }
        # clean that whitespace
        for key, value in sub_data.items():
             sub_data[key] = value.strip()
        collection[-1]['data'].append(sub_data)
    return collection
```

Okay that took me longer than I'm willing to admit. I wont lie. Gave me PTSD flashbacks from writing COBOL programs...

Anyway, now we have a nice, nested data structure in native python types. The fun can begin!

**Step 2: Load this into a usable format**

To analyze it, I'm assuming you'll want it in pandas (or maybe Dask if its too big). Here is what I was able to come up with along that front:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(
    collection, 
    record_path='data', 
    meta=["AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","HH","II"] 
)
```

A great reference for that can be found in the answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe) (particularly the second one, not the selected one)

**Put it all together now:**

```py
from typing import Dict
import pandas as pd

# load the file as raw input
with open('./test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# initialize  list of dicts
collection = []

def write_typhoon(row: str, collection: Dict) -> Dict:
    if row[:5] == '66666':
        typhoon = {
            "AA":row[:5],
            "BB":row[6:11],
            "CC":row[12:15],
            "DD":row[16:20],
            "EE":row[21:25],
            "FF":row[26:27],
            "GG":row[28:29],
            "HH":row[30:50],
            "II":row[51:],
            "data":[]
        }
        for key, value in typhoon.items():
            if key != 'data':
                typhoon[key] = value.strip()
        collection.append(typhoon)
    else:
        sub_data = {
            "A":row[:9],
            "B":row[9:12],
            "C":row[13:14],
            "D":row[15:18],
            "E":row[19:23],
            "F":row[24:32],
            "G":row[33:40],
            "H":row[41:42],
            "I":row[42:46],
            "J":row[47:51],
            "K":row[52:53],
            "L":row[54:57],
            "M":row[58:70],
            "P":row[71:]
        }
        for key, value in sub_data.items():
             sub_data[key] = value.strip()
        collection[-1]['data'].append(sub_data)
    return collection
    

# read through file sequentially
for line in lines:
    write_typhoon(line, collection)

# load to pandas df using json_normalize
df = pd.json_normalize(
    collection, 
    record_path='data', 
    meta=["AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","HH","II"] 
)
print(df.head(20)) # lets see what we've got!
```

Comment: Wow, that's a great answer. I'm not working on climate change, unfortunately. I'm making a video game where natural disasters are generated on a realistic time-scale :) Also unfortunately, I figured out how to do it myself by the time I saw your answer, though your efforts are much appreciated. I've added my own solution, but will accept yours since you went to such great lengths :)

Answer (score 0):

There's someone who might have had the same problem and created a library for it, you can check it out here:
https://github.com/miniufo/besttracks

It also includes a quickstart notebook with loading the same dataset.

Comment: Excellent, I actually just found this myself. It is most impressive!!! If I didn't have so much work, I'd love to up my skills by recreating his library!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up doing it. The key was realizing there are two types of rows in the data, but within each type the columns are fixed width:

```
header_fmt = "AAAAA BBBB  CCC DDDD EEEE F G HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH              IIIIIIII"
track_fmt  = "AAAAAAAA BBB C DDD EEEE FFFF     GGG     HIIII JJJJ KLLLL MMMM         P"
```

So, here's how it went. I wrote these two functions to help me reformat the text file int CSV format:

```
def get_idxs(string, char):
    idxs = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i - 1].isalpha() and string[i] == char:
            idxs.append(i)
    return idxs
    
def replace(string, idx, replacement):
    string = list(string)
    try:
        for i in idx: string[i] = replacement
    except TypeError:
        string[idx] = replacement
    return ''.join(string)

# test it out
header_fmt = "AAAAA BBBB  CCC DDDD EEEE F G HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH              IIIIIIII"
track_fmt  = "AAAAAAAA BBB C DDD EEEE FFFF     GGG     HIIII JJJJ KLLLL MMMM         P"

header_idxs = get_idxs(header_fmt, ' ')
track_idxs  = get_idxs(track_fmt, ' ')
print(replace(header_fmt, header_idxs, ','))
print(replace(track_fmt, track_idxs, ','))
```

Testing the function on the format strings, we see commas were put in the appropriate places:

```
AAAAA,BBBB, CCC,DDDD,EEEE,F,G,HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH,             IIIIIIII
AAAAAAAA,BBB,C,DDD,EEEE,FFFF,    GGG,    HIIII,JJJJ,KLLLL,MMMM,        P
```

So next apply those functions to the `.txt` and create a `.csv` file with the output:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

with ExitStack() as stack:
    
    read_file  = stack.enter_context(open('data/bst_all.txt', 'r'))
    write_file = stack.enter_context(open('data/bst_all_clean.txt', 'a'))
    
    for line in tqdm(read_file.readlines()):
        if ' ' in line[:8]: # line is header data
            write_file.write(replace(line, header_idxs, ',') + '\n')
        else: # line is track data
            write_file.write(replace(line, track_idxs, ',') + '\n')
```

The next task is to add the header data to ALL rows, so that all rows have the same format:

```
header_cols = ['indicator', 'international_id', 'n_tracks', 'cyclone_id', 'international_id_dup', 
               'final_flag', 'delta_t_fin', 'name', 'last_revision']

track_cols = ['date', 'indicator', 'grade', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'pressure', 'max_wind_speed', 
              'dir_long50', 'long50', 'short50', 'dir_long30', 'long30', 'short30', 'jp_landfall']


data = pd.read_csv('data/bst_all_clean.txt', names=track_cols, skipinitialspace=True)

data.date = data.date.astype('string')

# Get headers. Header rows have variable 'indicator' which is 5 characters long.
headers = data[data.date.apply(len) <= 5] 
data[['storm_id', 'records', 'name']] = headers.iloc[:, [1, 2, 7]]

# Rearrange columns; bring identifiers to the first three columns. 
cols = list(data.columns[-3:]) + list(data.columns[:-3])
data = data[cols]

# front fill NaN's for header data
data[['storm_id', 'records', 'name']] = data[['storm_id', 'records', 'name']].fillna(method='pad')

# delete now extraneous header rows
data = data.drop(headers.index)
```

And that yields some nicely formatted data, like this:

```
    storm_id    records name    date        indicator   grade   latitude    longitude
15  5102.0      37.0    GEORGIA 51031900    2           2       67.0        1614
16  5102.0      37.0    GEORGIA 51031906    2           2       70.0        1625
17  5102.0      37.0    GEORGIA 51031912    2           2       73.0        1635
```